# Possible values of $k$ in the given equation

Tags: contest-math, quadratics

> The equation $x^2-58x+k$ has both the roots prime and belong to integers.
>   What are the possible values of $k$?

I tried writing down 58 in all sums of two primes but I feel the list will go on.

Comment: What did you try first?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Tried breaking down 58 as a sum of two prime numbers but I feel the list will go on. Not sure how to do

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard. Will write answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viète's formulas tell us that the sum of roots is 58 and that the product of roots is $k$. All the decompositions of 58 into two primes follow, with the corresponding values of $k$.
$$5+53,k=265$$
$$11+47,k=517$$
$$17+41,k=697$$
$$29+29,k=841$$
Thus, these are all the possible values for $k$.

Comment: That's what I did but I got confused after this. Won't it also include pairs which are $a-b=58$?

Comment: @LinuxGeek But then the _sum_ of roots would not be 58. That was the _difference_.

Comment: The question doesn't specify that 58 should be a SUM of primes.

Comment: @LinuxGeek It **has** to be, by Viète's formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sum of the roots is $58=5+53=11+47=17+41=29+29$. Hence $k$, the product of the roots, can be $5\cdot 53$, $11\cdot 47$, $17\cdot 41$, $29^2$.